# Can I resolve service in windsor castle through some method call with parameters?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have IRFConfigurationSection which is instanced like this:

```
(RFConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings/ABZReportFactoryServer");
```

I want to put this call into Windsor castle and make this class singleton. So when I need to instance this RFConfigurationSection class, I'll like to do it this way.

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
configSection = container.Resolve<IRFConfigurationSection>();
```

Is it possible to somehow configure Windsor Castle config to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a better approach to use a factory, e.g:

```
public interface IConfigurationFactory<out TConfigurationSection>
{
    TConfigurationSection GetConfiguration();
}

public class RFConfigurationFactory : IConfigurationFactory<IRFConfigurationSection>
{
    public IRFConfigurationSection GetConfiguration()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings/ABZReportFactoryServer") as RFConfigurationSection;
    }
}
```

That way, you can add the factory to the container, and resolve an instance of that:

```
var configFactory = container.Resolve<IConfigurationFactory<IRFConfigurationSection>>();
var config = configFactory.GetConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<RFConfigurationSection>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings/ABZReportFactoryServer"))
        .LifeStyle.Singleton
);
```

Comment: But this way, this is not in config, it is in code. So when my section change I'll need to change it in all places.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You would only have to use this code once. It's the same as the xml configuration, but in code (with a fluent API) see http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Fluent-Registration-API.ashx